# Como criar um efeito da imagem levantar ao passar o mouse por cima

Tags: css

Sou novato aqui e sou básico em `CSS`.

Gostaria de saber como criar um efeito que, ao quando se passar o mouse por cima da imagem, ela levante um pouco.

Comment: você quer algo tipo isso aqui? http://www.kirupa.com/html5/slide_image_hover_using_css3.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Uma solução simples com css:

CSS:

```css
#teste{position:relative}
#teste:hover{top:-2px;box-shadow:0 2px 2px #666}
```

HTML:

```html
<img src="/imagem.png" id="teste">
```

Se quiser simplificar, para browsers mais velhos, basta usar um border no lugar do shadow:

```css
#teste{position:relative}
#teste:hover{top:-2px;border-bottom:2px solid #999}
```

### Incrementando com transitions:

Com transitions você consegue usar a mesma técnica acima, mas com o browser fazendo uma animação entre os estados normal e `hover`:

```css
#teste{position:relative;top:0}
#teste:hover{top:-4px;box-shadow:0 4px 4px #999;
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out}
```

Basta ajustar os parâmetros para o efeito desejado.

## Demo:

```css
#teste1{position:relative;padding:4px;background-color:#cf6}
#teste1:hover{top:-2px;box-shadow:0 2px 2px #666}

#teste2{position:relative;padding:4px;background-color:#cf6}
#teste2:hover{top:-2px;border-bottom:2px solid #999;padding-bottom:2px}

#teste3{position:relative;top:0;padding:4px;background-color:#cf6;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out}
#teste3:hover{top:-4px;box-shadow:0 4px 3px #999}
```

```html
Box-shadow (passe o mouse para testar):<br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizTJ.png" id="teste1"><br>
Simples, com border:<br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizTJ.png" id="teste2"><br>
Incrementado, com transition:<br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizTJ.png" id="teste3">
```

> Notar que em certas versões do IE o `hover` só funciona em elementos `a`.

Comment: Ajudou , bastante amigo

Comment: Ótimos exemplos!

Answer (score 4):

Se o que deseja é um efeito na imagem igual ao [deste exemplo](http://codepen.io/raphaelfabeni/full/Fkbej) do [Tableless](http://tableless.com.br/transition-e-animation/), é necessário usar CSS Transition e CSS Animation.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
    <img class="asterisco" src="http://tableless.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/logo-tableless-01.png" alt="Logo Tableless" />
    <img class="texto" src="http://tableless.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/logo-tableless-02.png" alt="Logo Tableless" />
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
body { background-color: #333; }    
a { color: #333; }    
.asterisco { transition: all 0.5s ease; }    
a:hover .asterisco { transform: rotate(180deg); }    
.texto { transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550); }    
a:hover .texto { transform: scale(1.2); }
```

Comment: Legal otimo , muito bom mesmo

Answer (score 0):

tem em javascript

```
    <script>
 function bigImg(x)
{
 x.style.height="64px";
x.style.width="64px";
}

  function normalImg(x)
{
x.style.height="32px";
x.style.width="32px";
}
</script>

<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">
```

Answer (score -4):

CCS:

```
img:hover{
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
      }
```

HTML:

```
<img src="/imagem.jpg"` >
```